# NetSuite SuiteTalk asyncAddList SoapFault

Tags: php, web-services, soap, wsdl, netsuite

I'm attempting to use NetSuite's SuiteTalk `asynchAddList` operation using the PHPToolkit_2015_1 to add multiple records asynchronously. Their [2015_1 WSDL](https://webservices.netsuite.com/wsdl/v2015_1_0/netsuite.wsdl) shows this is a valid operation:

```
<operation name="asyncAddList">
    <input name="asyncAddListRequest" message="tns:asyncAddListRequest"/>
    <output name="asyncAddListResponse" message="tns:asyncAddListResponse"/>
    <fault name="InvalidSessionFault" message="tns:InvalidSessionFault"/>
    <fault name="InvalidCredentialsFault" message="tns:InvalidCredentialsFault"/>
    <fault name="ExceededRecordCountFault" message="tns:ExceededRecordCountFault"/>
    <fault name="ExceededRequestSizeFault" message="tns:ExceededRequestSizeFault"/>
    <fault name="ExceededRequestLimitFault" message="tns:ExceededRequestLimitFault"/>
    <fault name="UnexpectedErrorFault" message="tns:UnexpectedErrorFault"/>
</operation>
```

I've tested my connection to NetSuite, and an `addList` request works without any issues. The `addList` and `asyncAddList` request XML is identical, except for the main tag within the body:

```
<Body>
    <asyncAddList>
        <record xsi:type="CustomRecord">
            <recType internalId="100" />
            <customFieldList>
                <customField scriptId="custrecord_name" xsi:type="SelectCustomFieldRef">
                    <value internalId="500" />
                </customField>
            </customFieldList>
        </record>
    </asyncAddList>
</Body>
```

While `addList` is successful, for an `asyncAddList` request I get this response:

`Fatal error: Uncaught SoapFault exception: [soapenv:Server.userException] An unexpected error occurred.`

In NetSuite's WebServices Usage Log, this operation isn't logged.

The WSDL shows the asyncAddList operation can return an `UnexpectedErrorFault`, but NetSuite's documentation only elaborates on this fault once
(`This fault is thrown in the event of an occurrence of an unexpected exception.`), but it's not very helpful.

Does anyone have experience using `asyncAddList` in SuiteTalk? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Update: I also tried to do an asyncUpdateList operation, and it also yielded a Fatal Error. A normal updateList operation however was successful. This seems to be a problem specifically with asynchronous operations.

Update #2: Async requests started working for one day, then stopped working for several, then started working again for one day. I have an open case with NetSuite support, and they're looking into the issue. Will update once they get back with a solution.

Answer (score -1):

I'm not really sure, but I remember having had similar issues using SOAP to connect to a 3rd-party application. It seems the login doesn't work. How do you call your function? You might have to perform a login before this call... 
I see that asyncAddList expects headers, so that might be it.
As I say, this is just a guess as I haven't worked with NetSuite yet. 
But I found your post looking for some answers myself. Maybe you can help be there:

[NetSuite - SuiteTalk - PHP - Install](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33511432/netsuite-suitetalk-php-install)

Comment: Is this an answer or a comment?

Comment: I am using NetSuite's PHP library and following the documentation. I initialize the service using my Web Service credentials and then submit the async request. Synchronous requests are successful. This issue relates only to asynchronous requests.