# NetSuite - SuiteTalk - PHP - Install

Tags: php, web-services, netsuite

I would like to build a gateway between a web-store (PHP) and Netsuite using SuiteTalk.

I am working on Ubuntu 14.04 and would like to set up the environment for testing.
Apache/2.4.7 etc.. is already up and running. Website is working.

Could someone give me an idea of the first steps I will need to go through in order to be able to develop and test the communication between my web application (PHP) and Netsuite.

Is a direct connection to Netsuite necessary at all? Is there a NetSuite sandbox?

I have been visiting these pages which seem to contain a lot of information on how to work with SuiteTalk:

http://www.netsuite.com.au/portal/platform/developer/suitetalk.shtml

http://www.netsuite.com.au/portal/developers/resources/suitetalk-sample-applications.shtml

As I said, it is just about the first steps to set up the environment for SuiteTalk, (java axis etc..)

Thanks to anybody who could help.

regards,

Answer (score 3):

First thing is you would need access to a NetSuite Test account, you can request a free community edition from [here](http://www.netsuite.com/portal/developers/sdn.shtml) . Sandbox account in NetSuite is provisioned only to a production NetSuite account users, which is a replica of live account.

Once, you have got access to a test account, you can read help topics like "Building an Application with Java using Apache Axis" and "Using the Web Services PHP Toolkit", which has step wise information on getting started, depending on you want to choose Java or PHP.

There are also code for sample application which you can try or your can write simple search on employee or customers once you have a test account and development environment ready.